# How to reduce horizontal ruler's width to the width of the document text in fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I use `fancyhdr` to customize my footer. But this code:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\lfoot{From: K. Grant}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

adds TWO rulers (top and bottom) with the width that is equal to the page width. I would like to reduce the width of the bottom ruler to the width of the main text and remove the top ruler. Plus, I would like the width of the text below the bottom ruler to be the same as the width of the main text. How to do this?

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention that I also use geometry package to adjust page margins. Maybe this is the source of the problem?

**UPDATE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\lfoot{Page \thepage}
\rfoot{some text}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT  
SOME LOOOOONG TABLE

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does your footer rule actually stretch from the left to the right page border?

Comment: @Yes, it does. P.S. See update in the question statement

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: Thanks, but you really should check that it compiles first.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that `fancyhdr` is working just fine. You are confused by the fact that the first paragraph is indented.  Add more test and you'll see.

Comment: load the package `lipsum` and then insert the command `\lipsum` in the documents body and you'll see that everything is fine.

Comment: @Peter: it compiles

Comment: @Peter: I don't see that everything is working fine. Everything is just as it was --- BAD.

Comment: See my updated answer. Let me know if that is not clear.  Otherwise, please explain what is **not** working as desired.

Comment: @Physicsworks: If you don't specify a unit, it defaults to `pt` (I think). As such, your left margin is actually set to `1.5pt`, not `1.5cm`. That gives the *illusion* that the rule spans the entire page width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the header rule, just add to your preamble

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
```

Note that by default the start of a paragraph is indented, so it *appears* that the horizontal rule is longer than the text:

[image]

But, once you add some additional text (here I have used the `\lipsum` package to provide dummy text), you can see that width of the rule from `fancyhdr` is the full text width:

[image]

This code is a corrected version of your MWE, with additional dummy text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\lfoot{Page \thepage}
\rfoot{some text}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT  
SOME LOOOOONG TABLE
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: FINALLY, this works perfectly! Thanks, +1 to this.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you load package `geometry` after package `fancyhdr`. Change the order, otherwise you'll get wrong margins for the header/footer

Comment: Actually, I've tried BOTH ways with the same final result... Any other ideas?

Comment: no, that's not possible. Then you have something different, which changes the margings after loading `fancyhdr`. Create a minimal and complete example and you'll find yourself what's wrong. Or show it here.

Comment: There is NO difference in the order of packages. I'll add the full code in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

In terms of removing the top (or header) rule, use

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

This is what the output looks like in a minimal document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\lfoot{From: K. Grant}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% remove header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\null \vfill Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Aenean faucibus auctor neque, quis vulputate purus facilisis et. 
\end{document}​
```

As you can see, the width of the footer (or header for that matter), including the rule, is the same as the text width (`\textwidth`), by default. As @Herbert suggests, you need to load [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) *before* you set any of the `fanchdr` settings. Here's what the output looks like if the order was reversed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\lfoot{From: K. Grant}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% remove header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\begin{document}
\null \vfill Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Aenean faucibus auctor neque, quis vulputate purus facilisis et. 
\end{document}​
```

Comment: to show the effect you need _two_ lines of text and not a complete page ...

Comment: Thanks, but this is the same code I have. Maybe the problem is that I use geometry package (see update in the question statement)?

Comment: @Werner: Perhaps include a margin adjustment in the `geomtry` settings, and I can delete my answer.  Also, I did not see any difference in the order of the package loading.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Good suggestion - done.